# Minecraft Agrarian skies server spawn to death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been trying to find a solution to the problem I'm having, which is that I spawn in the middle of nowhere and die right away in Agrarian skies. I can't find any sollution for multiplayer, only for singleplayer.

Is there anything I can change in my server to spawn on the actual island? Ive tried switching to creative mode and writing /jspawn, but that does nothing. I've also tried downloading the map and putting it in the saves folder, but that prob only works for singleplayer.

Anyone that has done this and knows what I need to do? please

Answer (score 3):

You need the multiplayer map or this will keep happening.

The multiplayer map has a spawn island in the center of it and is surrounded by a set of islands for people to fly to and play on. But this world is not generated, it has to be loaded in.

The map goes into the folder where the server's jar file is.

Comment: How do I "load it in" I have the multiplayer map downloaded but where do I put it?

Comment: @Max First, if you didn't do this already, extract the zip file, then rename the folder that comes out to "world" (without quotation marks) Then remove the folder "world" from the server folder (From where you start the server) and move the muliplayer map to the folder you made your server in. Now restart your server and you should be playing in your new world!